# POST request for JOIN table

Tags: rest, post, many-to-many, uri, naming-conventions

Let's say 3 tables

```
session
-------------------------
id | name | date
-------------------------

speaker
-------------------------
id | name 
-------------------------

session_speaker
-------------------------
session_id | speaker_id 
-------------------------
```

I've endpoints already in place to do the insertion

`POST /session` 
`POST /speaker`

What kind of REST request should I create to specify the intention to insert into the  JOIN table using `POST /session` or any other method (passing `session_id` and `speaker_id`)

**Note:** I've a `PATCH` request already in place to activate or deactivate a session.

Question:
Basically seeking an ideal REST based solution to handle CRUD based operations for the JOIN table, please advise.

Comment: @BenSmith please comment.

Comment: I didn't want to change the route, `/speakers`, I'm still open to ideas for insert. For `GET`, i took the solution from here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655046/rest-request-type-for-many-to-many-relationship/32700921#32700921 Can you please enhance your answer using this link

Comment: Hi @user2727195, sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I've updated my answer with regard to your use of the speakers route.

Comment: Did my updated answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following REST operation for creating the relationship:

```
PUT speakers/speaker/{speakerId}/session/{sessionId}/
```

I don't advise using plural names in URLs (e.g. speakers), I'd recommend a singular name such as SessionSpeaker, but as you can't change it from "speakers" I've used it as requested.

You should also use PUT instead of POST for inserting data, as PUT is [idempotent](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html) i.e. PUT guards against you inserting the same speaker at a session.

To then retrieve speakers information you could use:

```
GET speakers/session/{sessionId}
GET speakers/speaker/{speakerId}
```

Another good answer regarding REST and entity multiplicity is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5524030/203371).