# REST request type for many to many relationship

Tags: rest, uri, naming-conventions

Table structure

```
session
-------------------------
id | name | date
-------------------------

speaker
-------------------------
id | name 
-------------------------

session_speaker
-------------------------
session_id | speaker_id 
-------------------------
```

Request methods in place

```
a) GET /speakers (all speakers)

b) GET /speakers/:id (details on specific speaker)

c) GET /speakers/:id/sessions (list of sessions of a speaker)
```

Question

What type of request should I make to indicate I need not only the detail of the speaker but also it's sessions, essentially combining results of call (b) and (c) into one.

Also how is it done in real commercial projects? The client makes two calls (b & c) or do they develop another REST endpoint hence combing the results of b & c in a single call?

Or should the client make two requests?

Comment: I removed my answer, as this may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324547/how-to-handle-many-to-many-relationships-in-a-restful-api

Comment: please do attempt with your answer, I'm not finding answer in the suggested link, my question is specific to combining call (b) and (c) essentially into one.

Comment: I found an article that talks on this subject, please have a look. http://jaredscheib.azurewebsites.net/restful-api-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you could specify as query parameters which fields you want to have within your response payload. Something like:

```
GET /speakers/someid?fields=firstname,lastname,age,sessions
```

Another approach (a better one) should be to leverage the header `Prefer` (see this link for the specification: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240) to specify which kind of details you want to have within your response payload:

- `return=minimal`: only the speaker hints
- `include=sessions`: speaker hints and his / her sessions

Here is a sample:

```
 Get /speakers/someid HTTP/1.1
 Host: api.example.org
 Content-Type: application/json  
 Prefer: include=sessions
 Vary: Prefer,Accept,Accept-Encoding
```

Irakli Nadareishvili wrote an awesome blog post on this subject: http://www.freshblurbs.com/blog/2015/06/25/api-representations-prefer.html.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: ietf suggests the `return=representation` or `return=minimal`, however, blog is introducing `teaser`, not sure if these values are standard.

Comment: I want to follow the standards and neutral conventions without explicitly saying `include=sessions`, because I've several other many to many tables and don't wanna couple api's to entity names.

Comment: secondly `return=representation` means full join? (speakers with their sessions) and `return=minimal` means just speakers? Do you advise this methodology.

Comment: Also if data is coming the other way, i.e. an insert is happening, one kind of POST is adding speakers, but the other POST is Speaker + it's sessions (foreign keys for the join/junction table), how can I distinguish both operations

Comment: Also is there a header I could apply to specify an aggregate function output, for instance `SELECT MAX(speaker.lastModified) AS lastModified FROM speaker` to the endpoint `/speakers`